# Plot a curve in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

Suppose

```
a(x,y)=x*y-2*(x+y) and b(x,y)=y-x
```

How to plot the curve

```
{a(x,y)==0 && b(x,y)<0}
```

for `-1<= x <= 1` and `-1<= y<= 1`

in Mathematica?

---

Many Many thanks to all of you, especially  Kuba, Mr. Bob Hanlon, and Dr. José Antonio Díaz Navas.

Comment: See `ContourPlot`, `ImplicitRegion` etc.

Comment: Both in the same plot?

Comment: Yes. Both are in the same plot. That means plot x*y==2*(x+y) such that y<x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
ContourPlot[x*y - 2 (x + y) == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x - y <= 0]]
```

[image]

Of course, it gives the complete solution if the range in $x$ and $y$ is increased.

[image]

Comment: How to color this curve...

Comment: Use `ContourStyle -> Red` as an option, for instance

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = y /. Solve[{x*y == 2 (x + y), y - x < 0}, y][[1]]

(* ConditionalExpression[(2 x)/(-2 + x), 0 < x < 2 || x > 4] *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

```
f2[x_] = y /. 
  Solve[{x*y == 2 (x + y), y - x < 0, -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= y <= 1}, 
    y][[1]]

(* ConditionalExpression[(2 x)/(-2 + x), 0 < x < 2/3] *)

Plot[f2[x], {x, 0, 2/3}]
```

[image]